# About Page curling iOS

Tags: ios5, effect, page-curl

Sorry guys i have to solve a problem. 
I Want to implement in my app the famous effect Page curl that Apple show to us with its app iBook.
I read that the API are not public (very very bad...).
So the question is: is it really impossible to implement a page curl effect in an easy way? 
Thank to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using stroyboard. Then just create a segue from view to view and select partial curl as trasition style in the right tootlbar. (totally no coding)

Or if it is a modalviewController do something like set the animationtranistion property on the view to uianimationtrasisionstylecurlup and call subsequently presentmodalviewcontroller adn you are good to got. In this case you have to call, of course, to go back dismissmodalview.